# Batch Scripting: Command Not Running With If Statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

So for starters, I'm kind of a scrub coder and I'm enjoying playing around with batch scripting.
I don't like to have multiple command line windows open, so I'm trying to script everything into this 1 batch file, including the ability to run standard command line commands.

Here's the section of my code that I'm having issues with.

```
    :three
    echo.
    echo ***************************
    echo **Enhanced Command Prompt**
    echo ***************************
    :three.b
    echo.
    set /p Return=Enter Command: 
    if '%Return%'=='Return' goto home
    cmd /c %Return%
    goto three.b
```

NOTE: I've also removed cmd /c, and %Return% excutes with no issue, but for the sake personal preference, I've kept the cmd /c present.

The issue with this line of text, is executing a command such as "Ping Google.com" crashes the window. So does ipconfig /all, and anything else that doesn't seem to execute right away.
If I remove the "IF=Return", then I have no problems running ping google.com or anything else, but I'm ultimately trapped in this section of code without that IF statement.
The IF statement itself functions, but "Ping X" and other commands do not without crashing the batch file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem are the spaces. Test your code with single quotes in the `if` command replaced with double quotes (the proper way of quoting strings in batch files)

Comment: I love you.
That worked PERFECTLY. I couldn't understand why that 1 little IF statement would cause me so many problems, I had other IF statements that worked fine.
And since Batch scripting is so forgiving, I got the idea of using single quotes from a tutorial online.
Thank you again, so much!

Comment: @user3821353 Report that tutorial ;D

Comment: Is it possible to accept and upvote my answer or leave feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use double quotes in `if` as this is the proper way of quoting/comparing strings in batch file.

```bat
:three
echo.
echo ***************************
echo **Enhanced Command Prompt**
echo ***************************

:three.b
echo.
set /p Return=Enter Command: 
if "%Return%" == "Return" goto home
cmd /c %Return%
goto three.b
```